# Magento 2 Saving store configuration programatically in upgrade script

Tags: magento2, configuration, system.xml, core-config-data, upgrade-script

I want to save store configuration programtically but I'm just getting one problem after another. Firstly I wanted to use `Writer` class but since it only updates `core_config_data` table it doesn't work with more complex models like the one I want to update. Since updating the config by path works via `bin/magento config:set` I started digging and found out that by using `Magento\Config\Model\PreparedValueFactory` I should be able to create object with correct backend model name I have to save. Now the problem is that when I create the `PreparedValue` object it doesn't have the information - the `Magento\Config\Model\Config\Structure` class that's being instantiated during the `create()` and is responsible for giving access to system.xml configurations doesn't have any data from said files, it's methods don't return anything.

I'm sure I'm providing correct config path to the `Factory` so it's not that, it just looks like `Structure` doesn't have any configurations collected during the run of `PreparedValueFactory::create()`, can I do something about it or just admit defeat? Or maybe is there an easier method for saving store configs by path from upgrade scripts?

Answer (score 0):

I took couple steps back and decided to just run `bin/magento config:set` command from within the upgrade script and it works as intended.

Do do that you have to call `ConfigSetCommand::run()` and provide `ArrayInput` and `BufferedOutput` as parameters. Of course you can change them to something else that implements needed interfaces but I think that's the easiest way.